# CSS: Parpadeos indeseados con "transform: scale;"

Tags: html, jquery, css

Tengo un formulario-contenedor que muestra fotos con cierta información adicional; en realidad está incluido en un bucle de PHP, por lo que se muestran tres a la vez:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También tengo un script jQuery que añade ciertos estilos al pasar el ratón por encima de cada foto:

El problema está aquí:

```
$('.contenedor-top3').not(this).css({'filter': 'blur(15px)', 'transform': 'scale(0.85)'}); //A las otras dos fotos, las difumina
$(this).css({'transform': 'scale(1.25)', 'zIndex': '3'}); //Y a la elegida la agranda
```

La regla `transform: scale` funciona de manera muy tosca, haciendo temblar las fotos, que parpadeen, o que incluso se vean artefactos fugaces (he identificado una línea roja bastante aparente).

Lo cierto es que son anomalías que han empezado a ocurrir recientemente, tras hacer cambios en otras partes de la web que yo creo que no tienen nada que ver con ésta. Aunque tampoco tengo claro a raíz de qué cambios en concreto empezaron a ocurrir...

¿Se os ocurre qué puede ser?

He encontrado el siguiente enlace donde se detalla un problema muy similar:

https://www.iteramos.com/pregunta/62098/-transformacion-escala-causando-39-parpadear-39-cuando-se-pasa

Y se ofrecen soluciones relacionadas con ajustes del navegador, como por ejemplo:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Pero las he probado todas y ninguna parece funcionarme.

A ver si alguno sabe por dónde pueden ir los tiros. Gracias de antemano.

EDICIÓN: AÑADO "SNIPPET"

```js
/* Aplica estilos específicos -fijos- a las fotos del top 3 */

$(function() //En función de su puesto en la clasificación, aplica unos estilos u otros para que cada foto se situe en su sitio
{
    $('[data-contador2="1"]').css('left', '30px'); //Puesto en la clasificación
    $('[data-contador2="2"]').css('right', '50px');
    $('[data-contador2="3"]').css('left', '30px');

    $('[data-contador2="1"]').next().css('right', '40px'); //Estrella que contiene a la nota media
    $('[data-contador2="2"]').next().css('left', '40px');
    $('[data-contador2="3"]').next().css('right', '40px');

    $('[data-contador2="1"]').next().next().css('right', '62.5px'); //Nota media
    $('[data-contador2="2"]').next().next().css('left', '62.5px');
    $('[data-contador2="3"]').next().next().css('right', '62.5px');

    $('[data-contador2="1"]').parent().addClass('contenedor1'); //Contenedor de la foto
    $('[data-contador2="2"]').parent().addClass('contenedor2');
    $('[data-contador2="3"]').parent().addClass('contenedor3');

    $('[data-contador2="3"]').prev().css('margin-bottom', '75px'); //Da espacio inferior a la tercera foto para que se vea la sombra color bronce
    $('[data-contador2="3"]').next().next().next().css('margin-bottom', '75px');
    $('[data-contador2="3"]').next().next().next().next().css('margin-bottom', '75px');
});

/* Aplica estilos específicos a las fotos del top 3 al pasar el ratón por encima de una de ellas */

$(function()
{
    $('.contenedor-top3').mouseenter(function() //Al pasar el ratón por encima
    {
        let $contador2 = $(this).find('.numero-top3').data('contador2'); //Identifica el puesto en la clasificación de la canción

        if($contador2 == 1) //Si es la nº 1 le aplica unos estilos
        {
            $(this).find('.imagen-top3').addClass('sombra-oro');
            $(this).find('.numero-top3').addClass('numero-oro');
            $(this).find('.nota-top3').removeClass('oculto');
            $(this).find('.estrella-top3').removeClass('oculto');
            $(this).find('.ano-top3').css('color', 'mediumvioletred');
        }
        else if($contador2 == 2) //Si es la nº 2, otros
        {
            $(this).find('.imagen-top3').addClass('sombra-plata');
            $(this).find('.numero-top3').addClass('numero-plata');
            $(this).find('.nota-top3').removeClass('oculto');
            $(this).find('.estrella-top3').removeClass('oculto');
            $(this).find('.ano-top3').css('color', 'mediumvioletred');
        }
        else //Si es la nº 3 -no hay más-, otros
        {
            $(this).find('.imagen-top3').addClass('sombra-bronce');
            $(this).find('.numero-top3').addClass('numero-bronce');
            $(this).find('.nota-top3').removeClass('oculto');
            $(this).find('.estrella-top3').removeClass('oculto');
            $(this).find('.ano-top3').css('color', 'mediumvioletred');
        }

        $('.contenedor-top3').not(this).css({'filter': 'blur(15px)', 'transform': 'scale(0.85)'}); //A las otras dos fotos, las difumina
        $(this).css({'transform': 'scale(1.25)', 'zIndex': '3'}); //Y a la elegida la agranda
        $(this).find('.numero-top3').addClass('shake-slow shake-constant'); //Y hace que vibre el número
    });

    $('.contenedor-top3').mouseleave(function() //Al retirar el ratón, revierte los cambios
    {
        let $contador2 = $(this).find('.numero-top3').data('contador2');

        if($contador2 == 1)
        {
            $(this).find('.imagen-top3').removeClass('sombra-oro');
            $(this).find('.numero-top3').removeClass('numero-oro');
            $(this).find('.nota-top3').addClass('oculto');
            $(this).find('.estrella-top3').addClass('oculto');
            $(this).find('.ano-top3').css('color', 'black');
        } 
        else if($contador2 == 2) 
        {
            $(this).find('.imagen-top3').removeClass('sombra-plata');
            $(this).find('.numero-top3').removeClass('numero-plata');
            $(this).find('.nota-top3').addClass('oculto');
            $(this).find('.estrella-top3').addClass('oculto');
            $(this).find('.ano-top3').css('color', 'black');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).find('.imagen-top3').removeClass('sombra-bronce');
            $(this).find('.numero-top3').removeClass('numero-bronce');
            $(this).find('.nota-top3').addClass('oculto');
            $(this).find('.estrella-top3').addClass('oculto');
            $(this).find('.ano-top3').css('color', 'black');
        } 

        $('.contenedor-top3').not(this).css({'filter': 'blur(0px)', 'transform': 'scale(1)'});
        $(this).css({'transform': 'scale(1)', 'zIndex': ''});
        $(this).find('.numero-top3').removeClass('shake-slow shake-constant');      
    });
});
```

```css
/* COLORES */

:root {
    --color1: pink;
    --color2: mediumvioletred;
    --color3: purple;
}


/* FUENTES */

@font-face {
    font-family: "Web Symbols";
    src: url(../fuentes/WebSymbols-Regular.otf);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


/* ESTILOS GENERALES */

.oculto {
    display: none;
}

.icono {
    font-family: "Web Symbols";
} /*Convierte letras en iconos*/


/* BOTONES Y ENLACES */

.boton-enlace {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
    background: none;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
.boton-enlace:hover {
    color: var(--color2);
}
.boton-enlace:active {
    color: var(--color3);
}
.boton-enlace:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
} /*Simula un enlace a partir de un botón*/


/* TOP 3 GENERAL */

.contenedor-top3 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  transition: all 1s ease;
} /*Contenedor de las fotos*/

.contenedor1 {
    margin-top: 75px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.contenedor2 {
    top: 300px;
    left: 530px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.contenedor3 {
    top: 610px;
    left: 140px;
} /* Clases aplicadas por el script de jQuery a cada una de las fotos del top 3*/

.sombra-oro {
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px 20px #ffff9e;
}
.sombra-plata {
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px 20px grey;
}
.sombra-bronce {
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px 20px bisque;
} /*Sombras aplicadas por el script de jQuery a los contenedores de las fotos*/

.imagen-top3 {
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.numero-top3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  color: var(--color2);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 75px;
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 4px var(--color1);
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
} /*Puesto en la clasificación*/

.numero-oro {
    color: gold;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 14px yellow;
}
.numero-plata {
  color: silver;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 4px gainsboro;
}
.numero-bronce {
  color: #CD7F32;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 4px bisque;
} /*Estilos aplicados a los números de la clasificación por el script de jQuery*/

.estrella-top3 {
    position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  color: #f0ad4e;
  font-size: 4em;
} /*Estrella que sirve de fondo a la nota media*/
.nota-top3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 53px;
    color: sienna;
    font-weight: bold;
} /*Nota media en sí*/

.referencia-top3 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
.referencia-top3 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
.referencia-top3 a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--color1);
} /*Enlace que redirige a la web de la que se ha tomado la fotografía*/

.texto-top3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: powderblue;
  border: 2.5px solid lightblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 87.5%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.cancion-top3 {
    color: var(--color3);
  font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.autor-top3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.ano-top3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
} /*Año*/

.boton-vamos {
    margin-top: 517.5px;
    margin-left: 370px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    
    <head>

        <title>50 años de Era Pop</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

        <!-- Google Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rock+Salt&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

        <!-- CSShake -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://csshake.surge.sh/csshake.min.css"/>

        <!-- Animsition -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animsition/4.0.2/js/animsition.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../recursos/js/animsition.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animsition/4.0.2/css/animsition.min.css"/> 

        <!-- Charts.js -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>

        <!-- Sweet Alert-->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
        
        <!-- JS propio -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../recursos/js/audio_youtube.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../recursos/js/scripts.js"></script>

        <!-- jQuery Migrate -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        
        <!-- CSS propio -->
        <link href="../recursos/css/estilos.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="../recursos/css/estrellas.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="css/estrella.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    </head>

    <body>

    <main class="container">

    <section class="fotos" style="max-height: 1085px;"> <!--Sección con las tres fotos del top 3-->

        <div> <!--Bloque con la foto 1-->

          <form class="contenedor-top3" data-prueba="prueba" method="post" action="">

            <img class="imagen-top3" src="https://bit.ly/3bKioJU">

            <div class="numero-top3" data-contador2="1">1</div>

            <div class="icono estrella-top3 oculto">R</div>

            <div class="nota-top3 oculto">4,6</div>

            <div class="referencia-top3"><a href="https://bit.ly/3bKioJU" target="_blank">&copy;</a></div> 

            <div class="texto-top3">
              <span class="cancion-top3">Ace of spades</span>
              <span> de </span>  
              <span class= "autor-top3">Motörhead</span> 
              <span class="ano-top3">(<button class="boton-enlace" role="link" name="recopilatorio" value="">1980</button>)</span>
            </div>

          </form>

        </div>
        
        <div> <!--Bloque con la foto 2-->

          <form class="contenedor-top3" data-prueba="prueba" method="post" action="">

            <img class="imagen-top3" src="https://bit.ly/3q8lCeK">

            <div class="numero-top3" data-contador2="2">2</div>

            <div class="icono estrella-top3 oculto">R</div>

            <div class="nota-top3 oculto">4,1</div>

            <div class="referencia-top3"><a href="https://bit.ly/3q8lCeK" target="_blank">&copy;</a></div> 

            <div class="texto-top3">
              <span class="cancion-top3">Best of you</span>
              <span> de </span>  
              <span class= "autor-top3">Foo Fighters</span> 
              <span class="ano-top3">(<button class="boton-enlace" role="link" name="recopilatorio" value="">2005</button>)</span>
            </div>

          </form>

        </div>
        
        <div> <!--Bloque con cada una de las fotos del top 3-->

          <form class="contenedor-top3" data-prueba="prueba" method="post" action="">

            <img class="imagen-top3" src="https://bit.ly/3onioCO">

            <div class="numero-top3" data-contador2="3">3</div>

            <div class="icono estrella-top3 oculto">R</div>

            <div class="nota-top3 oculto">3,9</div>

            <div class="referencia-top3"><a href="https://bit.ly/3onioCO" target="_blank">&copy;</a></div> 

            <div class="texto-top3">
              <span class="cancion-top3">Town called Malice</span>
              <span> de </span>  
              <span class= "autor-top3">The Jam</span> 
              <span class="ano-top3">(<button class="boton-enlace" role="link" name="recopilatorio" value="1980">1980</button>)</span>
            </div>

          </form>

        </div>

            <button class="boton-vamos btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-decadas" type="submit">¡Vamos!</button>

      </section> <!--Fin de la sección de fotos-->

    </main>
    
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías generarnos un HTML/CSS/JS mínimo en el que se reproduzca el problema? Nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para facilitarnos la tarea de ver qué está ocurriendo con la animación.

Comment: No tengo muy claro que intentar reproducir el código en un snippet sirviese de algo, porque a priori no debería haber ningún problema al usar `scale`, y de hecho mi web funcionaba sin problemas. Hasta que dejó de funcionar. ¿Quizá podría subir un vídeo en el que navegue por esa parte de la web para que se vean los parpadeos?

Comment: Menos da una piedra. Pero ten en cuenta que reproducir un problema es el primer paso para poder desarrollar una solución a éste. En tu vídeo vería el problema, pero no podría probar soluciones o abrir el inspector de código para ver qué estilos están afectando a cada elemento.

Comment: Voy a intentar reproducir el código, pero la verdad es que nunca lo he hecho; ¿hay alguna guía de cómo hacer un snippet?

Comment: Es HTML, CSS y JavaScript, no tiene mucho misterio. También puedes subir la página a algún alojamiento donde podamos probarlo.

Comment: He añadido un snippet, pero al maximizar no se ve exactamente como debería -en pequeño, sí-. También me ha faltado añadir Web Symbols para que la R se convierta en una estrella, pero no la encuentro en línea. Lo demás creo que está todo. Incluyendo los dichosos parpadeos. No pensé que fueran a aparecer...

Comment: Mañana le echo un vistazo desde el ordenador. Desde el móvil no aprecio los problemas que sufres.

Comment: Perfecto. Prueba a pasar varias veces sobre cada foto porque de primeras a veces no se notan los problemas.

Comment: Yo te recomiendo algo: trata siempre de adjuntar los script antes del cierre de la etiqueta body http://lizzymendivil.blogspot.com/2017/08/script-antes-del-cierre-de-la-etiqueta.html

Comment: cuando hagas algún cambio y no veas efecto ctrl+f5 limpia la cache del navegador https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayuda:C%C3%B3mo_limpiar_la_cach%C3%A9

Comment: evita el uso de js en lo mas posible https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS
conoces el @keyframes de css3 puede que te sirva

Comment: Yo cambiaría bastante código JS por etiquetas CSS hover evita la ejecución de tanto script en tu máquina. Puede que esto te funcione

Comment: Mi problema es que no existe una maquetación fija, los contenedores de las fotos son creados dinámicamente con PHP. Por eso -creo que- no puedo recurrir simplemente a CSS.

Comment: No sé si es problema de tu equipo, navegador, o que no sé qué es lo que te falla, pero a mí se muestran correctamente las imágenes y el efecto de zoom, tanto desde el móvil como desde el ordenador (windows 10 y ubuntu 18.04). Además, que crees los contenedores dinámicamente no impide que hagas uso de CSS para su animación. Deberías probar a hacer los efectos solo con CSS y, como te recomienda @junior, evitar el uso de javascript para algo que pueda hacerse (quizá mejor) solo con CSS.

Comment: He eliminado el script que aplica estilos fijos utilizando ids dinámicas de tipo `id="elemento-top3-<?=$contador?>"`. Voy a ver qué se me ocurre para el otro.

Comment: Lo veo bien como @OscarGarcia desde Chrome Versión 89.0.4389.114 (Build oficial) (64 bits) en Ubuntu. La propiedad `transform` da problemas.. Prueba ponerle una Clase extra: `.no-flick{-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);}`

Comment: Mira este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946748/iphone-webkit-css-animations-cause-flicker)